# Segmentation Fault while trying to install julia packages

Tags: julia

I am having some trouble using `julia` on this new linux machine on which I have limited privileges.  For instances, I am getting a Segmentation Fault while trying to install a simple package.  As you can see, I am able to update the installation, getting the `toml` files from github, but the later instruction to install `Pluto` fails in a less then verbose way.

```sh
(py3+) [nuwjtv5@rh6-rd-ho-cloudera-07 ~]$ bat packages.jl
───────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: packages.jl
───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ using Pkg
   2   │ Pkg.update()
   3   │ Pkg.add("Pluto")
───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(py3+) [nuwjtv5@rh6-rd-ho-cloudera-07 ~]$ julia --version
julia version 1.5.2
(py3+) [nuwjtv5@rh6-rd-ho-cloudera-07 ~]$ julia packages.jl
 Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
######################################################################## 100.0%
      Added registry `General` to `~/.julia/registries/General`
   Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
  Resolving package versions...
julia: /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/cgmemmgr.cpp:831: virtual uint8_t* {anonymous}::RTDyldMemoryManagerJL::allocateCodeSection(uintptr_t, unsigned int, unsigned int, llvm::StringRef): Assertion `!code_allocated' failed.

signal (11): Segmentation fault
in expression starting at /export/home/nuwjtv5/packages.jl:3
Segmentation fault
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please open an issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/new and include the full stacktrace and information about your system (e.g. operation system, how you installed Julia etc).

Comment: Did you install Julia from the official binaries? If you installed Julia from your distro's package manager, that could be the problem.

Comment: How much RAM memory your process has to its disposal?

Comment: @prosoitos  I installed [this version](https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.5/julia-1.5.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz)

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, I don't think RAM is an issue.  The machine I am on has a couple hundred GB of RAM.

Comment: @fredrikekre,  I would like to open an issue, but I was hoping you could help me make sure that I am supplying the right information.   The operating system is a linux  (kernel 2.6.32-754.33.1.1.e16.x86_64).

Comment: Thank you all for helping me so far.

Comment: One last thing, I should also mention that I can't get the REPL to launch.  It just displays the banner and hangs!

Comment: Is this machine a Cray? (looking at the ancient Linux kernel). In that case there is a million of caveats on how to compile Julia on it.

Comment: The linux install is ANCIENT, but I have zero control on that.  I do have ANACONDA installed, so I might be able to make less ancient software and libraries availabl to julia.

Comment: Ok.  I opened an [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/37996)